# CSS - How to position this "menu" like on the UI design that I have made in Figma?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see from the title I want to know how to position this menu that I will show to you like on this UI design that I have made.

Here is the examples:
[image]

And here is how I tried to do it.

[image]

This is the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="root flexbox">
        <div class="navbar flexbox">
          <div class="container flexbox align-center">
             <img src="Slike/logo-avion.png" alt="">

             <div class="right-column flexbox align-center">
              <div class="navbar__navigation">
                <a href="" class="active">Početna</a>
                <a href="">Destinacija</a>
                <a href="">O nama</a>
                <a href="">Partner</a>
               </div>

               <div class="order-btn flexbox align-center">
                <a href="">Prijavi se!</a>
               </div>

               <div class="konj flexbox align-center">
                <a href="">Registriraj se!</a>
               </div>
                  
              </div>
            </div>
     
         </div>


        <div class="content">
          <div class="container flexbox">
            <div class="content__left_column">
              <h2>Ostvarite svoje
                putovanje iz snova!</h2>
                <p>Potraži svoj odmor na pravom mjestu!</p>
                <div class="linija">
                  <span class="linija crna-linija"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="kvadrati">
                  <div class="kvadrati prvi flexbox align-center ">
                    <p>Lokacija</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="kvadrati drugi flexbox align-center ">
                    <p>Aktivnost</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="kvadrati treci flexbox align-center  ">
                    <p>Ocjena</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="kvadrati cetvrti flexbox align-center">
                    <p>Datum</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__right_column">
              <img src="Slike/template_3_-_copy_dribble1dribble_1.png" alt="">
            </div>


          
          </div>
        </div>
          


         
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The div class `kvadrati` is used to make this menu. I know this may seem complicated to describe but I hope you know what I meant by asking this question. I tried using flexbox display and grid still failed. I am not a beginner in CSS but clearly this is something that I have a problem with.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.prvi {
    width: 22rem;
    height: 5.2rem;
    border-radius: 0.6rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid #afb0b9;
}
```

EDIT: Here is all of the styles.css

```
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Inter;
}

.right-column {
    margin-left: auto;
}
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
.container {
    width: 1300px;
    margin: auto;
}
.root {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
}
.align-center {
    align-items: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.navbar__navigation a {
    color: #b8becd;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.order-btn {
    height: 4.4rem;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid #57d2a3;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.order-btn a {
    padding: 21px 24px;
}

.navbar__navigation .active {
    color: #202336;
}

.konj {
    height: 4.4rem;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    background-color: #57d2a3;
}
.konj a {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 21px 24px;
}


.content__left_column {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.content__right_column {
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.content__left_column h2 {
    width: 55.9rem;
    color: #202336;
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    font-size: 6.4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 8rem;
}
.content__left_column p {
    margin-top: 69px;
    width: 40rem;
    color: #202336;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.linija {
    margin-top: 21px;
    width: 3.2rem;
    height: 0.3rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    background-color: #202336;
}
.kvadrati {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 70px 70px / 226px 226px;
    width: 226px;
    height: 52px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
}

.kvadrati div {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Hey Samed, please share your style.css file, that is needed in your example

Comment: We as comunity will try to help you, but you need to supply us the minimal working example (of code)  see this page for details > https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple issues with your code

```
                <div class="kvadrati">
                  <div class="kvadrati prvi flexbox align-center ">
                    <p>Lokacija</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="kvadrati drugi flexbox align-center ">
                    <p>Aktivnost</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="kvadrati treci flexbox align-center  ">
                    <p>Ocjena</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="kvadrati cetvrti flexbox align-center">
                    <p>Datum</p>
                    <img src="Slike/Vector.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see both the grid div `<div class="kvadrati">` and the items `<div class="kvadrati drugi flexbox align-center ">` share the same class `kvadrati`. As a result they both create a 2x2 grid. You should remove the `kvadrati` class on the 4 grid items.

```
.content__left_column p {
    margin-top: 69px;
    width: 40rem;
    color: #202336;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

And in this part of the code you give the `<p>` elements a `margin-top: 69px;`. This causes the `<p>` Items in your grid to move down 69 pixels. You could change `<p>Potraži svoj odmor na pravom mjestu!</p>` to a `<h3>` style it using a class so it doesn't affect the other `<p>` elements.

Alternatively, since you probably want a dropdown list, you can avoid this by using `<select>` tags instead. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp) for a guide on creating a custom select.

**-----------**

Here is a simple example on how to use a grid to create a 2x2.

If you need more information on how to use css grid, read [on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.grid div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is some kind of solution. It helps me make this grid but when I want to insert <p> into the divs the <p> is below all grids. I can not make it go into the divs if you know what I mean, just like from the picture above

Comment: You'll need to share the relevant portion of your `css`, then I can take a look

Comment: I have identified a couple problems, see my answer

Comment: Thank you it fixed my problems

Comment: If you do not need any additonal help please consider accepting the answer. Thanks!